# Matlab matrix interpolation with 4 known values

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have 4 known (corner) values of an matrix:

```
grid = [2 5
        5 8];
```

This values are my corners and I want to interpolate between them, that I get a non-squared matrix, e.g. a 350x250 matrix.

I searched some familiar questions but I couldnt find a solution or wasnt able to transfer it to my problem. I found the `interp2` function but not how to tell that I only have the 4 corner values?

I made an easy example to show what I need and what doesnt work (or what I am doing wrong):

```
test = [2 0 0 0 8
        0 0 0 0 0
        6 0 0 0 12 ];

[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:5,1:3);

M = interp2(X,Y,test,X,Y);
```

The resulting matrix is exactly the same as the input matrix `test`. How can I interpolate the zeros? In general my Input is only this:

```
grid = [2 8; 6 12];
```

Comment: If you read the documentations and examples: "X and Y contain the coordinates of the sample points. V contains the corresponding function values at each sample point" so you need your coordinates, if you want 350x250, then place the 4 points at (1,1),(350,1),(250,1),(350,1) and use your values for V. As simple as that.

Comment: could u please make an example for me I got a bit confused by all the sample, query and coordinates?

Comment: I think `interp2` will work just fine. Use the 3 argument version. Anyway, usually the resolution is what matters rather than the gridsize, so I would guess that you need to adjust the values after resolution. For 2 points you can probably use 348 and 248 for 250-by-350 values, but I have not tested. You should take a look at the documentation and try it by yourself. In case you really want to set the grid you need to define a grid and use the 5 argument version.

Comment: I tried different things about the interp2 function but the results doesnt make sense .. I created a Matrix 350x250 with zeros and pasted my corner values at the corners `[(1,1),(1,250),(350,1),(350,250)]` and then I used the interp2 function: `M2 = interp2(intp,[1 250 350 250],[1 1 1 350]);` the result is a 4x1 vector: `2.0000    4.1404    5.0000       NaN` I also tried the long version with 5 parameters but maybe Im doing somthing wrong with the parameters: `[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:350,1:250);
M = interp2(X,Y,intp,1:250,1:350);` the result is the same (intp: the 350x250 zero matrix with values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long thinking I found a solution:

```
x = 350;
y = 250;

V = [2 8
     6 12];

[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:2,1:2);

a = linspace(1,2,x);
Xq = a(ones(1,y),:); % oder repmat([1 n], y);

b = linspace(1,2,y)';
Yq = b(:,ones(1,x));

M = interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq);
```

I hope it helps anybody who has the same problem, I didnt understood that the final size is only in the last two parameters present.